# How can i find the size of a materialized view log in oracle?

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I need to find the mview log size to drop those logs and also the status of the mview to know if it is active or not. help me to find these details.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your user privileges, the `DBA_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES` or `ALL_MVIEW_REFRESH_TIMES` dictionary views will tell you when a materialized view was last refreshed.

The `ALL_MVIEW_LOGS` or `DBA_MVIEW_LOGS` views will give you information about the logs themselves, including their underlying tables, and the `ALL_REGISTERED_MVIEWS` or `DBA_REGISTERED_MVIEWS` views will tell you which materialized views are known and whether they are capable of using the MV Logs.

An MV Log should automatically purge itself up to the current point in time when all registered materialized views have completed their refreshes.